# Select Count of Distinct rows and sum

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Item     |     Document
-----------------------
Book     |      BL
Book     |      CT
Book     |      OP
Pen      |      CT
Pen      |      BL
Mug      |      OP
```

I need to get the count of all unique items and the count of all documents in that table.  For the example above, I'm looking for an output like this:

```
3        |     6

3 - Book, Pen, Mug
6 - total count of available documents
```

My SQL looks like this:

```
 SELECT ITEM , COUNT (*) AS DOC_COUNT
    FROM TABL1
  GROUP BY ITEM
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 0
```

But I'm only getting the list of all items with their document count.
Can someone help me figure out how to solve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Elementary, my dear Watson.

```
select count ( distinct item ) as item_count
     , count ( document )      as doc_count
from   tabl1
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
SELECT item ,
  MAX(ITEMS_)ITEM,
  MAX(DOC_)DOC,
  MAX(ro_num)TOTAL_ITEM
FROM
  (SELECT item,
    row_number() over (partition BY ITEM order by ITEM DESC)ITEMS_,
    row_number() over (partition BY document order by document DESC ) DOC_,
    MAX(rownum) over (partition BY 1)ro_num
  FROM table1
  )
GROUP BY item
```

Comment: I'd guess this takes 4x the time of @mathguy's solution.

Comment: Yes but will give different result as well

Answer (score 0):

If your expected output is

```
3        |     6

3 - Book, Pen, Mug
6 - total count of available documents
```

Kindly try the below query

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (COUNT (DISTINCT item)) AS item_count, 
       TO_CHAR (COUNT (document)) AS doc_count 
  FROM (SELECT item, document FROM table1) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT    COUNT (item) 
       || ' - ' 
       || LISTAGG (item, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY item) 
          items, 
       NULL 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT item 
          FROM ( (SELECT item, document FROM table1))) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT COUNT (document) || ' - total count of available documents' document, 
       NULL 
  FROM (SELECT document 
          FROM ( (SELECT item, document FROM table1)))
```

You can use ROLLUP as well

```
  SELECT item, COUNT (item)
    FROM table1
GROUP BY ROLLUP (item)
ORDER BY item
```

[Example](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_EXSWIGR0NRV2Z4B5HQRMFFLUW.html)